# How can I check User Input value again Django Models and Forms

Tags: python, django

I don't know how to actually write the logic but I want to check user inputs especially price form field against Product model (price property).

I have model the django form as below:

```
class SalesForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Sales
    fields = ['product', 'customer', 'quantity', 'price']
```

Here is the Product Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORY, null=True)
cost = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
price = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

Here is what  I am trying to do logically in views.py

```
def user_add_sales(request):

sales = Sales.objects.all().order_by('-salesdate')[:5]
if request.method == 'POST':
    sales_form = SalesForm(request.POST)
    if sales_form.is_valid:
        sales_price = sales_form.cleaned_data('price')
        try:
            user_input = Product.objects.get(price = sales_price)
            sales_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Sales Added Successfully')
            return redirect('dashboard-user-sales')
        except user_input.DoesNotExist:
            sales_form = SalesForm()
else:
    sales_form = SalesForm()
context = {
   'sales' : sales,
   'sales_form' : sales_form,
}
return render(request, 'dashboard/user_sales.html', context)
```

When  Try running the code, says 'SalesForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'. Someone should please help me on how I can check whether what the user enters in price field of the SalesForm is not less than the price set for that product in Product Model.

Answer (score 2):

The form is validated by the `sales_form.is_valid()` *method*, not by an attribute, the if condition is thus:

```
if sales_form.is_valid():
    # …
# …
```

In your form, you can check if the given price is at least the price in the related attribute with:

```
class SalesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # …
    
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super().clean(*args, **kwargs)
        if data['price'] < data['product'].price:
            raise ValidationError('The price of the sale is below the price of the product')
        return data
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but What  Want to achieve here is to check whether value entered inside the price field is NOT less than the one set in the price property of the Product Model

Comment: Can you share your `SalesForm`?

Comment: The SaleForm code is the first code in my question. Just take a look at the code on top. Thanks

Comment: @apollos: you can check this by overriding the `clean` method.

Comment: `class SalesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sales
        fields = ['product', 'customer', 'quantity', 'price']`

Comment: As Willem Van Onsem said you can use froms validation and it will handle everything. As you want to check does the value number or not. Add your validation what you want to check and it's will take care of it. If you want to show errors then you can use something  like in your template `froms.errros.price`